# Visual Studio shows syntax error after notepad++ edit .py file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, notepad++

Endcoding is utf-8 without BOM.

Actually I tried every encoding, but it doesn't solve problem. I don't know whats wrong.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Would you please copy and paste the error you are getting?

Comment: No error message, no code example... How are we supposed to help you? Read http://stackoverflow.com/help to learn how to ask a question...

Comment: If you have visual studio and notepad++ installed. You can duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is inconsistent whitespace type of thing. At Notepad++ Settings->Preferences>Tab Settings check "Replace by space". The problem fixed. Now I enjoy Notepad++.